# Getting NSInvalidArgumentException when posting a Dictionary to Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add an array of custom objects to a Firestore Database. The Dictionary looks as follows:

```swift
        for (n, eventInArray) in currentEvents.enumerated() {

            ref.updateData(["Events":
                                [n:
                                    ["activity": eventInArray.activity],
                                 ["dateAndTime"]: ["date": eventInArray.dateAndTime.date,
                                                   "time": eventInArray.dateAndTime.time],
                                 "name": eventInArray.name
                                ]])}
```

But when running the app and sending the data, I get following error message:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber getBytes:maxLength:usedLength:encoding:options:range:remainingRange:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xd628e63903198e1c'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to work around this issue.

Instead of updating one field, I updated the whole document using a do - catch block:

```
    do {
        try ref.setData(from: groupDataForDb)
    } catch let error {
        print("Error writing to firestore \(error)")
    }
```

The groupDataForDb variable is a struct that conforms to Codable, and has properties matching the fields in the Firestore Document.